# basename command is not working in jenkins

Tags: bash, shell

Created one jenkins parameterized job. where 
userspecificlocation --> full path of the file.

```
ssh ubuntu@$ip -n  "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/$userlistlocation . --region eu-central-1"
fbname=`basename $userlistlocation` 
echo "$fbname"
```

I have tried this on my local machine it's working fine but from the jenkins box echoing gives empty value.

Tried in one more way but that didn't worked too.

```
fbname=$(basename $userlistlocation) ; echo $fbname
```

Comment: What is the value in `$userlistlocation`? and what is the output to `$fbname`

Comment: userlistlocation value can be anything user input. For example here we can take as /rahul/example.csv
fbname variable should have the rahul.csv.

$fbname will be used in my final command.

Comment: And what is the output of `$(basename /rahul/example.csv)`?

Comment: the output should be example.csv

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: it's printing as echo $fbname

Answer (score 1):

backticks `` `blah` `` are deprecated, and generally `$(blah)` should be used instead, but really, `basename` is not needed, just use parameter expansion, like so:

```
printf '%s\n' "${userlistlocation##*/}"
```